# My Sql Connection error Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I am trying to connect to MySql database with c#. But i am getting this error.

```
   Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.
```

My c# code

```
 Connection con = new Connection();
        Recordset rs = new Recordset();
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
        con.Open(conStr);  // Here its throwing the error
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=localhost;Database=laundrydatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=123"
         />
```

I am using

```
mysql-connector-net-6.6.5
MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say you are using ODBC 5.1 driver but in connection string you say 5.2. Can you try without specifying the driver in the connection string?

Comment: @Vivekh : Why don't you try mysql .Net/C# drivers instead of ODBC driver.

Comment: Yes i have tried them and i am working with them now but just wanna know why i am not able to connect via ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

You have the MySQL ODBC driver 5.1 installed but your connection string says version 5.2. This means the system cannot find the driver and that is indicated by the second half of the error message. the easiest way to fix is to remove the driver reference from connection string:

```
Server=localhost;Database=laundrydatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=123
```

Or if you need to specify the driver, fix the reference like this:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=laundrydatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=123
```

Comment: Does it work if you put `Option=3;` on the end of the connection string?

Comment: Are you sure the driver is installed? Can you create a connection using the Windows ODBC control panel applet?

Comment: Yes i have configured it now and tested connection from there it connected successfully

Comment: What options did you pick from there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57903/discussion-between-vivekh-and-davidg).